# Cannot override bootstrap with css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I add bootstrap to my html document it changes the font-size of my h1 tag to 2.5rem. For some reason I can't override this with my css file. even with the !important attribute.

I made sure my custom stylesheet is loaded after the bootstrap in order on the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles/style.css">
    </head>
<body>
 <h1 class="logo">TIGERS</h1>
</body>
```

This style section is in the styles.css file linked above

```
    .logo {
        font-size: 3.5em !important;
    }
```

Also: something weird is that when I put the css inline, eg.

```
<h1 class="logo" style="font-size: 3em">TIGERS</h1>
```

it works.

any help is appreciated

Comment: Can you try with h1.logo or only with h1?

Comment: Actually, it works perfectly: https://jsfiddle.net/td5xcg2k/ Make sure that there is no other `<style></style>` tag within your script that can override your css rules and it should work perfectly

Comment: Just to confirm, you do not have the <style> tag in your CSS file?

Comment: @AugustoM no, in my stylesheet I never actually put the style tags, I changed the question, I just put them there for readability but that ended up having the opposite effect

Comment: @JoshuaVandenbor have you tried F12 tools and check which properties are being rendered and where it is coming from? You can also switch the position of your links to see if that affects the rendering.

Comment: @JoshuaVandenbor can you confirm that the stylesheet is FOUND? I mean if the link is not broken. ---href="./styles/style.css"

Comment: Yes just confirmed that. The other styles listed in the style sheet are being applied. Also just simply removing the bootstrap link the header will return to the style I expect

Comment: Could this have anything to do with the fact that I am using scss to generate the css file?

Comment: @JoshuaVandenbor no, it will not be anything to do with you using SCSS, All that SCSS does is create the CSS file and your CSS looks correct.

Answer (score 1):

You would only use the `<style>` tags when CSS is set inline, not if in an external CSS file.

The style should look like this in `style.css`:

```
.logo {
    font-size: 3.5em !important;
}
```

i.e. no `style` tags.

Comment: Thanks for improving the answer @LGSon

Comment: Sorry I guess I didn't make that clear. my actual stylesheet never had the <style> tags in it. I just put that there to indicate css. will revise question